# Python random number generator giving the same value every time

Tags: python-3.x, random, random-seed

I am using Python for a sampling problem. Part of the problem requires the diagonal of a matrix to be filled with either a '1' or '-1' with equal probability of either.

I am trying to use random.choice as shown below but the list I get always contains only'1' or '-1'

```
k = 10 
diag = []   
for i in range(0,k):
    diag.append(random.choice((1,-1)))
```

I have looked up seeding at different points by doing things like:

```
random.seed(numpy.sin(time.clock()))
```

and placing the seed in the for loop before the random choice is made but I get the same outcome.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?

Comment: Never put the seeding inside the `for` loop.  Always seed once, outside the loop.  You are seeding from the clock, and the loop will execute before the clock ticks again, so it will reset back to the same seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `choice` method accepts a `size` argument to produce an output array of a given length. You can simply do this:

`diag = np.diag(np.random.choice([-1,1], size=...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your wording suggests that you want a matrix, but you don't specify anywhere what the non-diagonal elements should be.  Assuming uniformly distributed in [0,1) we can do:

```
import numpy as np

k = 5
X = np.random.rand(k, k)
X[np.diag_indices(k)] = np.random.choice((-1, 1), k)
```

gives me:

```
[[-1.    0.95  0.73  0.60  0.16]
 [ 0.16  1.    0.87  0.60  0.71]
 [ 0.02  0.97 -1.    0.21  0.18]
 [ 0.18  0.30  0.52  1.    0.29]
 [ 0.61  0.14  0.29  0.37 -1.  ]]
```

after setting the seed to 42, and rounding to 2 decimal places.